# Не приходит уведомление при получении письма из программы на C#

Tags: c#, email, sendmail, outlook

Отправляю письмо из программы на C#. Почта Outlook.
Письмо приходит, но без уведомления, просто во входящих новое письмо появляется.
Как сделать, чтобы уведомление появлялось?
Обычные письма (не из программы) приходят с уведомлением.

```
SmtpClient Smtp = new SmtpClient();
Smtp.Host = "...";
Smtp.Port = 25;
Smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
Smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
Smtp.EnableSsl = false;
Smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("name1@....ru", "pass");
MailMessage email = new MailMessage();
email.From = new MailAddress("name1@....ru");
email.To.Add(new MailAddress(sendemail));
email.Subject = "test";
email.Body = "test";
Smtp.Send(email);
```

Comment: Ваш код будет??

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик, добавила код

Comment: Если вы имеете ввиду уведомления клиента Outlook на рабочем столе, то вероятнее всего проблема в Outlook. Проверьте настройку Параметры Outlook => Почта => Получение сообщения = >Выводить оповещения на рабочем столе

Comment: Также на этом [форуме](http://www.techsupportforum.com/forums/f57/solved-outlook-desktop-alert-not-working-488530.html) решалась такая проблема.

Comment: @Exodium, уведомления включены, когда обычные письма приходят, уведомление появляется, именно при отправке из программы не появляется

Comment: В аутлуке могут быть настроены правила, отключающие уведомления для конкретных писем. Предлагаю проверить списки правил.

Comment: @Qwertiy, проверила правила, нет связанных с проблемой правил. Сейчас попробовала в outlook сама себе отправить - уведомление появляется, а через прогу отправляю сама себе - не появляется.

Answer (score -1):

Возможно свойство [MailMessage.DeliveryNotificationOptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.deliverynotificationoptions(v=vs.110).aspx) Вам поможет.

Из описание MSDN: Возвращает или задает уведомления о доставке для данного сообщения электронной почты.